# Footnotes overlapping with page number

Tags: footnotes, page-numbering

I'm using `fancyhdr` and having trouble distancing the page number(positioned center of the page in the footer) from the footnotes on a page of my documentation. I have posted a couple of images showing how the footer should look like[image: How the page should look like] and what my problem is[image: Roman number iii overlapping the footnotes]. Please provide a solution to this problem.

Thank you.

This is the code that I have been working on,

```
\usepackage{fancyhdr}
\thispagestyle{fancy}
\renewcommand{\headrulewidth}{0pt}% No header rule
\renewcommand{\footrulewidth}{0pt}% No footer rule
\fancyfoot[C]{Acknowledgements reflect the views of the author and are not endorsed by committee members or Oklahoma State University.{\thepage}}%
\pagebreak
```

Right now, the page number "iii" is being displayed at the end of the footer. I would like the roman number to be displayed as shown in image 1.

Comment: Apologies for the poor clarity of images. As you can see the roman number (iii) is overlapping the footnote. Please let me know if you have any questions.

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SX! Please make a minimal example (TeX code), which shows the problem and can be reproduced by others for analyzing the problem.

Comment: Thank you @HeikoOberdiek!
\thispagestyle{fancy}

\renewcommand{\headrulewidth}{0pt}% No header rule

\renewcommand{\footrulewidth}{0pt}% No footer rule

\fancyfoot[C]{Acknowledgements reflect the views of the author and are not endorsed by committee members or Oklahoma State University{\thepage}}%
\pagebreak

Right now, I have the roman number (iii) being displayed at the end of the footer. I would like the roman number to be displayed as shown in figure 1.

Comment: You can edit your question to add the code.

Answer (score 1):

My guess from the code snippet is, that there is a clash of the entries for `\fancyfoot`:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{fancyhdr}
\renewcommand*{\headrulewidth}{0pt}
\renewcommand*{\footrulewidth}{0pt}
\fancyfoot[L]{Acknowledgements reflect the views of the author and are not
endorsed by committee members or Oklahoma State University.}
\pagestyle{fancy}

\begin{document}
\pagenumbering{roman}
\setcounter{page}{3}
\null
\end{document}
```

> [image: Reproduction]

The issue can be solved by moving the left entry below by an empty line to get the requested outcome:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{fancyhdr}
\renewcommand*{\headrulewidth}{0pt}
\renewcommand*{\footrulewidth}{0pt}
\fancyfoot[L]{\mbox{}\\Acknowledgements reflect the views of the author
and are not endorsed by committee members or Oklahoma State University.}
\pagestyle{fancy}

\begin{document}
\pagenumbering{roman}
\setcounter{page}{3}
\null
\end{document}
```

> [image: Result]

Example with smaller font size for the acknowledgement text:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{fancyhdr}
\renewcommand*{\headrulewidth}{0pt}
\renewcommand*{\footrulewidth}{0pt}
\fancyfoot[L]{%
  \vspace{.6\baselineskip}
  \footnotesize
  Acknowledgements reflect the views of the author and
  are not endorsed by committee members or Oklahoma State University.%
}
\pagestyle{fancy}

\begin{document}
\pagenumbering{roman}
\setcounter{page}{3}
\null
\end{document}
```

> [image: Result smaller font size]

Comment: Thanks a lot @Heiko! I have another query here, how do I reduce the font size of the footer?
I'm using a page break to move to the next page and the text above is being chopped off. Possible solution to this?

Comment: @Sunny First question, see updated answer. The second question is not clear to me. You can edit your question to clarify the problem.

Comment: Thank you for your quick response. Do you mind looking at the question I posted a little earlier?
Here is the link -- http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/260615/adjusting-text-size-in-footer