# Adjusting Text Size in Footer

Tags: header-footer, fontsize

[image: Footnote being cut-off at the end of the page, would like the text to be on the same page]

Here is the code that I have been using. I have a couple of questions here,

1. How to reduce the size of text in footer so that it is not chopped off at the end of a page?
2. Move the text in the footer to center of the page. When I move it using `\fancyfoot[C]`, the page number seems to be missing. I would like the page number also to be displayed.

Please take a look at the code below,

```
\usepackage{fancyhdr}
\thispagestyle{fancy}
\renewcommand*{\headrulewidth}{0pt}
\renewcommand*{\footrulewidth}{0pt}
\fancyfoot[L]{\mbox{}\\Acknowledgements reflect the views of the author and are not endorsed by committee members.}
\pagestyle{fancy}
\pagenumbering{roman}
\setcounter{page}{3}
\null
\pagebreak
```

Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

The page number is set at the center of the footer by default. If it is overwritten by `\fancyfoot[C]`, then the page number is lost unless reinserted:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{fancyhdr}
\renewcommand*{\headrulewidth}{0pt}
\renewcommand*{\footrulewidth}{0pt}
\fancyfoot[C]{%
  \thepage\\
  \footnotesize
  Acknowledgements reflect the views of the author and
  are not endorsed by committee members or Oklahoma State University.%
}
\pagestyle{fancy}

\begin{document}
\pagenumbering{roman}
\setcounter{page}{3}
\null
\end{document}
```

> [image: Result]

If the text is too near the bottom of the page, then you might want to decrease the text height.

Comment: Thank you @Heiko! The code is working fine for me. Is there any way to further reduce the size of the font?

Comment: @Sunny Smaller than `\footnote` is `\scriptsize` or `\tiny`.